# Box Collider 2D using Z axis

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

2D means that only X an Y axis matters but when i do `OnTriggerStay2D(COllider2D col)` and do `Debug.Log(col.gameObject)` it is fine as long as both objects stay at the same Z axis value (0, 0). When i move one of my objects to different value, they no longer collide. Why is this happening and how to fix it?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Why do you need to make a movement on Z axis ?

Comment: Easier to organize then using `OrderInLayer` for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objects with different Z value will not collide, as Collider2D is also 2D which lies on XY plane and the Z is same as the objects Z.
So, if you change Z of a 2D object they wont collide. Hopefully the attached image clarifies.
[image]

For different Z valued objects to collide, you'll need to use 3d colliders.

Comment: Oh. I misunderstood 2d collider then. I will use 3d colliders but is there any significant difference in performance between 2d and 3d colliders?

Comment: 3D colliders obviously need more physics calculations than 2D colliders, but that isn't so significant, as there are many 3D games already running in low end devices.

Comment: it's for android, that is why i ask. Thanks for answers.

Comment: No problem. You can use it. I have used it in android games too.

Comment: This answer is not correct -- at least in Unity 2019.4. Game objects using 2D colliders and with different Z-values will still collide.

Comment: This answer is INCORRECT